# PHP's passthru() vs shell_exec()

Tags: php

The function `passthru()` is good when the output contains binary data as the function outputs the raw output. However, the documentation for the function `shell_exec()` does not say whether the data returned is binary safe (=raw).

So, my question here is that does `shell_exec()` return the **raw** output? Or do I need to use `ob_start()`, `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_end_clean()` with `passthru()` to get the raw output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns a string with the data written to the standard output. Strings in PHP are binary safe; they can contain `\0` characters.

Such characters will be included in the result of `shell_exec()` if the executed command resulted in those characters being written. What you do with that is up to you.

Output buffering is irrelevant here; `shell_exec()` doesn't output anything to the client, it only returns a string.

Comment: So, are you saying the only difference between `shell_exec()` and `passthru()` is that one outputs directly where the other returns the output. Well, `passthru()` also supports the return var. I need to get the contents of some binary data, I have used `passthru()` before because the documentation says it outputs **raw** data. Am I good to go with `shell_exec()` too?

Comment: @rFactor No, the return var that passthru gives is the return status of the command.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm unclear. I want to retrieve raw binary data. I can either do it with `output buffering` and `passthru()`, or I could just use `shell_exec()`. My question is that is `shell_exec()` capable of handling that raw output? I'm confused because the PHP doc says `passthru()` being capable of outputting **raw** data, while it never mentions that in the `shell_exec()` page.

Comment: Yes, shell_exec(...) *does* handle raw data.